# Does updating iOS force you to update watchOS?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos

First there was watchOS 1 which shipped with iOS 8.x.

Then there was watchOS 2 which shipped with iOS 9.

Now there is watchOS 3 which ships with iOS 10.

The question: if you start with watchOS 1 & iOS 8, and then update your iPhone to iOS 9 or 10, is the user then required to update their Apple Watch to the latest rev that comes with iOS?

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't force you to update your Apple Watch. You can use an Apple Watch with older versions of watchOS while using iOS 10 on your iPhone.

You won't be able to use any features that are exclusive to iOS 10 or higher watchOS versions, though. Think standalone watchOS apps (watchOS 2.x and higher), iMessage animations (watchOS 3.x and higher), new watch faces and so on.